# Fetch Min Max Value from Multiple Objects

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

I have 5 different objects 
**Obj1__c, 
Obj2__c, 
Obj3__c, 
Obj4__c, 
Obj5__c**

Each Object has Date Field
**Start_Date__c, 
End_Date__c**

Now I need to find out ***Min Start_Date__c*** And ***Max End_Date__c*** . By Querying all there should be one Min Date and One Max Date.
Is it Possible by SOSL? or need to use collection one by one with if else conditions?

Comment: You have to write five soql query for five objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Aggregate function.
It make code simple and shorter

```
List<AggregateResult> eleTr = [SELECT MIN(From_Date__c) minD1, MAX(To_Date__c) maxD2,Rent_Schedule__c FROM Electric_Transaction__c where Rent_Schedule__c = : rentScheduleIds GROUP BY Rent_Schedule__c];
        if(eleTr != null){
            RentScheduleCalculations_Helper.addDatesToList(eleTr);
        }
        List<AggregateResult> wtrTr = [SELECT MIN(From_Date__c) minD1, MAX(To_Date__c) maxD2,Rent_Schedule__c FROM Water_Transaction__c where Rent_Schedule__c = : rentScheduleIds GROUP BY Rent_Schedule__c];
        if(wtrTr != null){
            RentScheduleCalculations_Helper.addDatesToList(wtrTr);
        }
        List<AggregateResult> gasTr = [SELECT MIN(From_Date__c) minD1, MAX(To_Date__c) maxD2,Rent_Schedule__c FROM Gas_Transaction__c where Rent_Schedule__c = : rentScheduleIds GROUP BY Rent_Schedule__c];
        if(gasTr != null){
            RentScheduleCalculations_Helper.addDatesToList(gasTr);
        }
        List<AggregateResult> phnTr = [SELECT MIN(From_Date__c) minD1, MAX(To_Date__c) maxD2,Rent_Schedule__c FROM Phone_Transaction__c where Rent_Schedule__c = : rentScheduleIds GROUP BY Rent_Schedule__c];
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using the `sort()` method on your List of dates? Below is an example I have created using the CreatedDate value for 2 Contacts in my Org.

For your case, you will need to query each object you want to retrieve the date fields for.

```
List<DateTime> createdDates = new List<DateTime>();
List<Contact> cons = [select id, CreatedDate from Contact limit 2];

For(Contact c : cons) {
    createdDates.add(c.CreatedDate);
}

createdDates.sort();

DateTime minDate = createdDates.get(0);
DateTime maxDate = createdDates.get(createdDates.size()-1);

System.debug('Min : ' + minDate + ' Max : ' + maxDate);
```

By sorting the list of DateTime values we can obtain the minimum and maximum values.

You can modify the data type from `DateTime` to `Date`.

Comment: As Mentioned in the Question. I want to get Max and Min Date out of 5 Objects. At the End there should be One Min And One Max Date.

Comment: Yes once you obtain the Date values for each object you are interested in you will then be able to perform a sort() on the collection of Dates. Once sorted, the lists first position will be your MIN while its last will be your MAX.

Comment: 1. Create a new list of type Date and add all the dates of these 5 objects 2.Execute sort

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new list of type Date and add all the dates of these 5 objects     2.Execute sort         3.Take the first element from the list - this will be the minimum     4.Take the last element - it will be the maximum
   Something like so:
   List dtlIst = new List();
   dtlist.add(Date.today());
   dtList.add(Date.newInstance(2016,11,22));
   dtList.add(Date.newInstance(2016,09,22));
   dtList.sort();

System.debug(dtlIst[0]);
System.debug(dtlIst[dtlIst.size()-1]);